# AdapterNotSpecified deploying Rails app to Heroku using ClearDB for MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cleardb

I'm trying to revive an old Rails application I worked on several years ago. I'm using ruby 2.3.3 and rails 3.2.15 on the Heroku-16 stack with ClearDB for my MySQL database with the mysql2 adapter. When deploying to Heroku it succeeds on the deploy but crashes when it tries to start the app.

Full stack trace from the Heroku log (updated after fixing activerecord-import gem version per suggestion in first answer):

```
2021-02-09T04:42:26.851155+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2021-02-09T04:42:27.370829+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584256+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness/orm/active_record.rb:17:in `<module:ClassMethods>': undefined method `version' for ActiveModel:Module (NoMethodError)
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584311+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness/orm/active_record.rb:6:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584336+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness/orm/active_record.rb:3:in `<module:ORM>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584380+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness/orm/active_record.rb:2:in `<module:ValidatesTimeliness>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584424+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness/orm/active_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584467+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584499+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584532+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584595+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584621+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness.rb:59:in `block in load_orms'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584647+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness.rb:59:in `each'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584674+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness.rb:59:in `load_orms'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584701+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness/railtie.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584758+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584787+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584813+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584843+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584924+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.584985+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/validates_timeliness-4.1.1/lib/validates_timeliness/railtie.rb:4:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585018+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585058+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585108+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585158+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585189+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585220+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585255+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585334+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585368+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585401+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585432+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585511+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585548+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585579+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585659+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585692+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585723+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585764+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585837+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585868+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585900+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585930+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.585977+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.586026+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.586055+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.586087+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.586120+00:00 app[web.1]: from script/rails:6:in `require'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.588043+00:00 app[web.1]: from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2021-02-09T04:42:30.758954+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-09T04:42:30.840167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Line 6 from environment.rb as referenced in the stack trace:

```
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Heroku Config Vars:

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql2://user:pw@us-cdbr-east-03.cleardb.com/db?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL: mysql2://user:pw@us-cdbr-east-03.cleardb.com/db?reconnect=true
RACK_ENV: production
RAILS_ENV: production
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
```

From database.yml:

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
```

From Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.15)
      actionpack (= 3.2.15)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (3.2.15)
      activemodel (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.15)
      activemodel (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activerecord-import (0.4.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    activeresource (3.2.15)
      activemodel (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
    activesupport (3.2.15)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.3.4)
    akami (1.2.0)
      gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    attr_encrypted (1.2.1)
      encryptor (>= 1.1.1)
    audited (3.0.0)
    audited-activerecord (3.0.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      audited (= 3.0.0)
    axlsx (2.0.1)
      htmlentities (~> 4.3.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.1)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0.0)
    axlsx_rails (0.3.0)
      axlsx (>= 2.0.1)
      rails (>= 3.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2-x86-mingw32)
    better_errors (0.8.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.0.4)
    bumbler (0.3.1)
    byebug (5.0.0)
      columnize (= 0.9.0)
    capistrano (2.15.5)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
      capistrano (>= 1.0.0)
    capistrano-log_with_awesome (0.0.2)
      capistrano (>= 2.5.14)
    capistrano-sidekiq (0.5.3)
      capistrano
      sidekiq
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    childprocess (0.5.6)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chromedriver-helper (0.0.7)
      nokogiri
    chronic (0.10.2)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.3)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    connection_pool (2.2.0)
    crack (0.4.2)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    curb (0.9.7)
    d3-rails (3.5.5)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    database_cleaner (1.0.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.1.1)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise_security_extension (0.7.2)
      devise (>= 2.0.0)
      rails (>= 3.1.1)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    encryptor (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    ffi (1.9.10-x86-mingw32)
    font-awesome-rails (4.3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    gpgme (2.0.2)
    gyoku (1.1.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    handlebars_assets (0.20.2)
      execjs (~> 2.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.0.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.2)
    hashie (3.4.1)
    highline (1.6.20)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hitimes (1.2.2)
    hitimes (1.2.2-x86-mingw32)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    httpi (2.1.0)
      rack
      rubyntlm (~> 0.3.2)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    imgkit (1.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_request (0.2.3)
      rack-contrib
      railties
    mime-types (1.25)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    mysql2 (0.3.17)
    net-scp (1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-sftp (2.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.7.0)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    newrelic_rpm (3.13.0.299)
    nguyen (1.0.1)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.6)
    nokogiri (1.5.10)
    nokogiri (1.5.10-x86-mingw32)
    nori (2.3.0)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    paperclip (3.5.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.7)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-contrib (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-ssl (1.3.4)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.15)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.15)
      actionpack (= 3.2.15)
      activerecord (= 3.2.15)
      activeresource (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.15)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (3.2.15)
      actionpack (= 3.2.15)
      activesupport (= 3.2.15)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.2.1)
    redis-namespace (1.5.2)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    rolify (3.2.0)
    rspec-core (2.14.7)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.4)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.4)
    rspec-rails (2.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    ruby-ole (1.2.11.7)
    rubyXL (3.1.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      rubyzip (>= 1.0.0)
    rubyntlm (0.3.4)
    rubyzip (1.0.0)
    rvm-capistrano (1.5.1)
      capistrano (~> 2.15.4)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.2.12)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    savon (2.3.0)
      akami (~> 1.2.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      gyoku (~> 1.1.0)
      httpi (~> 2.1.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0, < 1.6)
      nori (~> 2.3.0)
      wasabi (~> 3.2.0)
    selenium-webdriver (2.46.2)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    shoulda-matchers (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    sidekiq (3.4.2)
      celluloid (~> 0.16.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
      json (~> 1.0)
      redis (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.2)
    sidekiq-failures (0.4.5)
      sidekiq (>= 2.16.0)
    sinatra (1.4.6)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    soda-ruby (0.2.13)
      hashie
    spreadsheet (0.9.4)
      ruby-ole (>= 1.0)
    spring (1.3.6)
    spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)
      spring (>= 0.9.1)
    sprockets (2.2.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    teaspoon (1.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.5, < 5)
    teaspoon-mocha (2.2.4)
      teaspoon (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timeliness (0.3.7)
    timers (4.0.1)
      hitimes
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.2.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    validates_timeliness (3.0.14)
      timeliness (~> 0.3.6)
    vcr (2.9.3)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    wasabi (3.2.0)
      httpi (~> 2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0, < 1.6)
    wash_out (0.8.4)
      nori (>= 2.0.0)
    webmock (1.17.4)
      addressable (>= 2.2.7)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
    websocket (1.2.2)
    whenever (0.8.4)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.4)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-import (= 0.4.1)
  addressable
  attr_encrypted
  audited-activerecord (~> 3.0)
  axlsx_rails (= 0.3.0)
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bumbler
  bundler
  byebug
  capistrano
  capistrano-ext
  capistrano-sidekiq
  capistrano-slack!
  capybara
  chromedriver-helper
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  curb (= 0.9.7)
  d3-rails
  database_cleaner
  devise
  devise_security_extension
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  font-awesome-rails
  gpgme
  handlebars_assets
  imgkit
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  launchy
  meta_request (= 0.2.3)
  mysql2 (= 0.3.17)
  newrelic_rpm
  nguyen
  paperclip
  rails (~> 3.2.14)
  rails_12factor
  rolify
  rspec-expectations
  rspec-rails
  rubyXL
  rvm-capistrano
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  savon
  selenium-webdriver
  shoulda-matchers
  sidekiq
  sidekiq-failures
  sinatra
  soda-ruby
  spreadsheet
  spring
  spring-commands-rspec
  teaspoon-mocha
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  validates_timeliness
  vcr
  wash_out
  webmock
  whenever
  wkhtmltoimage-binary!

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.3p222

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

I've been beating my head against this all day, reading every Stack Overflow and support article I could find and haven't figured out where my configuration is wrong.

Comment: Can you share the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're running into compatibility issues trying to use the latest version of the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem at the time of writing (released in October 2020) with activerecord 3.2.22.5 (released in September 2016). You do mention it's a rails 3.2.15 app but you're not using activerecord 3.2.15 which is confusing.

Try using **activerecord-import 0.4.1** (released in July 2013) and **activerecord 3.2.15** which should be compatible with rails 3.2.15.

Comment: After this change it is still crashing on app start, but now getting an error on validates_timeliness gem. I'm updating the version on that and giving it a try. Your answer may have got me on the path to getting this solved. I'll update as I make progress. Thanks!

Comment: Updating the validates_timeliness gem was the final hurdle. The application now starts and does not immediately crash. Thanks again for the pointer!